# Content page not displaying

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a custom keyboard below is the xaml for the view, after all configuration it shows a blank page.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomKeyboard" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="CustomKeyboard.MainPage" Title="Custom Keyboard App" BackgroundColor="White">
   <ScrollView>
      <Grid Padding="15">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Entry Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Placeholder="Regular entry..." />
         <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <local:EntryWithCustomKeyboard x:Name="entry1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0, 0, 0, 20" Keyboard="Text" TextColor="Black" Placeholder="Custom Keyboard entry..." />
            <local:EntryWithCustomKeyboard x:Name="entry2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Text" TextColor="Black" Placeholder="Custom Keyboard entry 2..." />
         </StackLayout>
         <BoxView Grid.Row="2" />
      </Grid>
   </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: have you tried adding a Label with text to your layout to verify that it displays?  I have no idea what `EntryWithCustomKeyboard` so it seems likely that the issue might be inside that class.

Comment: Thanks have been able to fix the issue, the reason for  the issue is the  namespace of the content page on the xml, it doesn't match the renderer class namespace